# Simple proof of L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to prove the following result (along with understanding its conditions) *without using Stolz-Cesáro’s theorem and the one Wikipedia has got*.

> Assume that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions on an open interval $I$ containing the real number $a$. Moreover $g\ne0$ and $g'\ne0$ on that interval. Also assume that $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L$ for some real number $L$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=+\infty$, then:
>
> $\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$

I would be grateful if you don't include post graduate concepts. Keep it as simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: The condition $g\ne0$ does not hold.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**:

$$L=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h}{{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h}{}}=\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}.$$

If we can swap the limits,

$$L=\lim_{h\to0}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{g(a+h)-g(a)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)}{g(a+h)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$

Comment: Can you explain why the swapping of limits is justified here ? Thanks.

Comment: How do you justify $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h}{{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h}{}}=\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}$? The two $\lim_{h\to0}$ might approach their limits at different rates.

Comment: @martycohen: the ratio of two limits equals the limit of the ratio.

Comment: What about $\frac{\lim_{x \to 0}1/x}{\lim_{x \to 0}1/x}$?

Comment: @martycohen: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik: I didn't justify it. I said "If we can swap". This is only a hint.